# Apache 2.4 mod_wsgi windows server multiple hosting - not running more than two Django projects

Tags: django, web-hosting

**httpd.conf file**

```
ServerName 172.31.4.38
Listen 8001
Listen 8002
Listen 8003
LoadFile "C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python311.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/Lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp311-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311"
WSGIPythonPath "D:/adhocvenv/Lib/site-packages"
```

**virtual host configuration **

```
<VirtualHost *:8001>
    ServerName 172.31.4.38
    
    WSGIScriptAlias / "D:\adhocvenv\adhocpayroll\adhocpayroll\wsgi.py" application-group=site1

    <Directory "D:\adhocvenv\adhocpayroll">
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8002>
    ServerName 172.31.4.38
    #DocumentRoot "D:/StoreManagementSystem"

    WSGIScriptAlias / "D:/StoreManagementSystem/StoreManagementSystem/wsgi.py" application-group=site2
    <Directory "D:/StoreManagementSystem">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:8003>
    ServerName 172.31.4.38
    DocumentRoot "D:/HealthCenter"
        
    WSGIScriptAlias / "D:/HealthCenter/HealthCenter/wsgi.py" application-group=site3

    <Directory "D:/HealthCenter">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**
Log file:
**

```
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:12.293908 2023] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 33144:tid 320] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.784193 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355] mod_wsgi (pid=38164): Failed to exec Python script file 'D:/HealthCenter/HealthCenter/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.784193 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355] mod_wsgi (pid=38164): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'D:/HealthCenter/HealthCenter/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.785189 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.785189 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]   File "D:/HealthCenter/HealthCenter/wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.785189 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]     application = get_wsgi_application()\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.785189 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.785189 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]   File "D:\\adhocvenv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.785189 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.785189 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]   File "D:\\adhocvenv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\__init__.py", line 19, in setup\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.785189 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.785189 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.785189 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]   File "D:\\adhocvenv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.785189 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]     self._setup(name)\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.786184 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]   File "D:\\adhocvenv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 89, in _setup\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.786184 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.786184 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.786184 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]   File "D:\\adhocvenv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 217, in __init__\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.786184 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.786184 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.786184 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]   File "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\importlib\\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.786184 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.786184 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.786184 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.786184 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.786184 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1126, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.786184 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.786184 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.786184 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.786184 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r
[Thu Nov 23 17:09:13.786184 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 38164:tid 2216] [client 172.31.4.38:57355] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'StoreManagementSystem'\r
```

**
First two projects are running successfully. For the third projects its showing internal server misconfiguration. What is the wrong with the above configurations?

Why misconfiguration? I've verified that each site works individually.**

Comment: Could you please share the Apache error logs, which are typically located in "/var/log/apache2/error.log"

Comment: added in the question. thanks